# Python boto bucket.list() return "no element found'

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to get the last file uploaded to AmazonS3. It seems the only way is to get all keys metadata, sort by date then load the right one by name.

```
conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key, calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())

bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name, validate=False)

for item in conn.make_request("HEAD", bucket_name).getheaders():
    print('bucket header ->',item)

boto.set_stream_logger('paws')

for current_key in bucket.list():
    print('in loop')
    print(current_key)
    #current_key = bucket.get_key(current_key.name)
    #print(current_key.get_metadata('revision'))
```

Here is the console result :

```
bucket header -> ('x-amz-id-2', '25NUgCAlVd2PMfzIgEI0bzpvNBkXasFL9cpxpf3wUJbxnLBCuf0VLf1wiul13Z2lF06qNwfF3ss=')
bucket header -> ('x-amz-request-id', 'AF98E73E5BCF1838')
bucket header -> ('Date', 'Tue, 19 May 2015 08:21:29 GMT')
bucket header -> ('Last-Modified', 'Tue, 28 Oct 2014 11:30:14 GMT')
bucket header -> ('ETag', '"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"')
bucket header -> ('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')
bucket header -> ('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
bucket header -> ('Content-Length', '0')
bucket header -> ('Server', 'AmazonS3')
2015-05-19 10:21:25,180 paws [DEBUG]:path=/GA-Exports/Events_3112/
2015-05-19 10:21:25,180 paws [DEBUG]:auth_path=/GA-Exports/Events_3112/
2015-05-19 10:21:25,180 paws [DEBUG]:Method: GET
2015-05-19 10:21:25,180 paws [DEBUG]:Path: /GA-Exports/Events_3112/
2015-05-19 10:21:25,180 paws [DEBUG]:Data: 
2015-05-19 10:21:25,180 paws [DEBUG]:Headers: {}
2015-05-19 10:21:25,183 paws [DEBUG]:Host: s3.amazonaws.com:443
2015-05-19 10:21:25,183 paws [DEBUG]:Port: 443
2015-05-19 10:21:25,183 paws [DEBUG]:Params: {}
2015-05-19 10:21:25,183 paws [DEBUG]:establishing HTTPS connection: host=s3.amazonaws.com, kwargs={'timeout': 70, 'port': 443}
2015-05-19 10:21:25,200 paws [DEBUG]:Token: None
2015-05-19 10:21:25,200 paws [DEBUG]:StringToSign:
GET


Tue, 19 May 2015 08:21:25 GMT
/GA-Exports/Events_3112/
2015-05-19 10:21:25,200 paws [DEBUG]:Signature:
AWS [_accesskey_]:oIo0Qk6pCn+pMPzarqRs4Pb3AvE=
2015-05-19 10:21:25,200 paws [DEBUG]:Final headers: {'Date': 'Tue, 19 May 2015 08:21:25 GMT', 'User-Agent': 'Boto/2.38.0 Python/3.4.3 Windows/8', 'Authorization': 'AWS [_accesskey_]:oIo0Qk6pCn+pMPzarqRs4Pb3AvE=', 'Content-Length': '0'}
2015-05-19 10:21:25,669 paws [DEBUG]:Response headers: [('x-amz-id-2', 'FzO+CIljQO4DKnEusv0Lm/qns5C1hP+REZ0YlYp+TV+XlxT6AKLacHG//UWMOsKGz1vuuVIZ2t4='), ('x-amz-request-id', '52D92D3D21FFD93D'), ('Date', 'Tue, 19 May 2015 08:21:30 GMT'), ('Last-Modified', 'Tue, 28 Oct 2014 11:30:14 GMT'), ('ETag', '"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"'), ('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes'), ('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'), ('Content-Length', '0'), ('Server', 'AmazonS3')]
2015-05-19 10:21:25,669 paws [DEBUG]:b''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Francois\OneDrive\IDE\Workspace\eclipse\Python_test\etltest.py", line 33, in <module>
    for current_key in bucket.list():
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\bucketlistresultset.py", line 34, in bucket_lister
    encoding_type=encoding_type)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\bucket.py", line 472, in get_all_keys
    '', headers, **params)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\bucket.py", line 406, in _get_all
    xml.sax.parseString(body, h)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\__init__.py", line 46, in parseString
    parser.parse(inpsrc)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py", line 125, in parse
    self.close()
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 217, in close
    self.feed("", isFinal = 1)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 211, in feed
    self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
    raise exception
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:1:0: no element found
```

Also the bucket.get_all_keys() raise the same exception...

Is it possible I have the permissions to get a specific file by name but not the permissions to list the bucket keys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your runs code successfully in my account, so it is likely a permission-related issue.

The important thing to note is that permissions to **list** the bucket apply to the bucket, while permissions for objects **within** the bucket apply to the contents of the bucket.

You'd need a policy that applies permissions like this (taken from [Example )Policies for Administering AWS Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies_examples.html)):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET-NAME"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that `ListBucket` uses `"arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET-NAME"`, while `PutObject` uses `"arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET-NAME/*"`.

The easiest test is to try your code with a policy that permits ALL S3 functionality, and then scale-back the policy to suit requirements.